# Как получить значение слайдера?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

В WPF/MVVM приложении в модели нужно получить значение слайдера из формы, как это сделать?
Мой метод не работает.

```
class GameSpeed
{
    public enum Speed : int { STOP, SLOW, NORMAL, FAST };

    public void GetSliderSpeed(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        int val = (int)(e.NewValue);
    }
}
```

[image]

**Edit 1**

**View**

```
    <Slider SmallChange="1" Maximum="3" TickPlacement="BottomRight"
    Value="{Binding Path=GameSpeed.SpeedSlider}" />
```

**VM**

```
    private GameSpeed _gameSpeed;
    public GameSpeed GameSpeed
    {
        get { return _gameSpeed; }
        set
        {
            _gameSpeed = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

**Model**

```
class GameSpeed
{
    public GameSpeed()
    {
        SpeedSlider = (int)Speed.SLOW;
    }

    private int _speedSlider;
    public int SpeedSlider
    {
        get { return _speedSlider; }
        set
        {
            if (value > -1 && value < 4)
                _speedSlider = value;
        }
    }

    public enum Speed : int { STOP, SLOW, NORMAL, FAST };

    public void GetSliderSpeed(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        int val = (int)(e.NewValue);
        MessageBox.Show(val.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: А как он должен работать? Я почему то не вижу у вас ни привязок, ни обращения по имени к контролу, как Slider у вас вообще задействован?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Обновил код. Теперь для view можно установить значение из модели, а наоборот все еще нельзя

Comment: Как вы поняли, что "нельзя"? Я вижу у вас `MessageBox`, который находится в `GetSliderSpeed`, по нему вы проверяете? Если да, то вопрос тот же, как задействован ваш `GetSliderSpeed`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да, проверяю по MessageBox. Да в том и дело, что я не знаю, как задействовать метод GetSliderSpeed или любой другой метод при перемещении ползунка слайдера.

Comment: Ну самый простой вариант - засунуть в `Set` свойства `SpeedSlider` нужный метод и он будет вызываться каждый раз, когда вы измените это свойство.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо, получилось